# Discrete Maths Dual graphs

Tags: graph-theory

This is a question on an exam and they have written a dual graph in the solution. My question is how can I see that it is a dual graph? I know that a Dual graph is a complement to a Planar graph. It is question 5 from this link below. [https://people.kth.se/~bek/diskret/tentor/16/okt16As.pdf](https://people.kth.se/%7Ebek/diskret/tentor/16/okt16As.pdf)

> We must decide whether for the adjacent graph there is a closed curve in the plane that crosses each edge exactly once and does not go through any vertex.

> **Solution:** Such a curve corresponds exactly to an Euler circuit in the dual graph, but it has two vertices with odd degree (corresponding to the triangular regions in the center), so no Euler circuit.

> **Answer:** No, there is no such curve.

Sorry, it is in Swedish if you want to read the exam.

Comment: The question asks to decide "whether... there exists a closed curve... that **crosses each edge exactly once...**". This is the hint that leads to consider the dual graph, the reason is that there is a one to one correspondence between edges in the primal graph and edges in the dual graph.

Comment: fidbc please explain a little more?

Comment: See definition of dual. Also, the condition on crossing exactly one edge exactly once suggests considering an Euler trail in the dual.

Comment: @AndrewUzzell was it really necessary to edit a question from 2016 to fix the grammar?

Comment: @MishaLavrov, perhaps it would have been better if I had refrained.